# Why can't ruby use most of the 2^X numbers as object ids?

Tags: ruby

`ObjectSpace._id2ref` gives us the object from the Ruby's Object Space, it has an object against id in sequence starting from 0, however, if we try to see object on id 4 it gives an error as

```
2.6.3 :121 > ObjectSpace._id2ref(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):121
        1: from (irb):121:in `_id2ref'
RangeError (0x0000000000000004 is not id value)
```

Also, I figured that it's the same behaviour for 2^x values(except 1, 2, 8).

```
(0..10).each do |exp|
  object_id = 2**exp
  begin
    puts "Number: #{object_id} :  #{ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id)}"
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Number: #{object_id} :  #{e.message}"
  end
end

Number: 1 :  0
Number: 2 :  2.0
Number: 4 :  0x0000000000000004 is not id value
Number: 8 :  nil
Number: 16 :  0x0000000000000010 is not id value
Number: 32 :  0x0000000000000020 is not id value
Number: 64 :  0x0000000000000040 is not id value
Number: 128 :  0x0000000000000080 is not symbol id value
Number: 256 :  0x0000000000000100 is not id value
Number: 512 :  0x0000000000000200 is not id value
Number: 1024 :  0x0000000000000400 is not id value
```

Why can't ruby use these specific numbers as object ids?
Also, what's different for `(1,2,8)`? and why error is different for `128`?

Comment: In short - up to a certain id, the ids are used for [interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) certain values. Some of the values have formulas. For example, small integers are stored in id `n * 2 + 1`. And some are hardcoded at specific id. Simply put, for the values you've found there is no overlap in the formulas. But it's not really powers of 2. For example, `12`, `24` and `28` also error out. [If you want to read about it in more details](http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/object.html).

Comment: Every object has an id. But not every id refers to an object. The error message _"... is not id value"_ simply means that the given id doesn't refer to an object. This may change when creating new objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is very important to make a couple of things crystal clear:

1. There are exactly two guarantees Ruby makes about object IDs. These two guarantees are the *only* thing you are allowed to rely on. You *must not* make any assumptions about object IDs other than these two guarantees:

   - An object has the same ID for its entire lifetime.
   - No two objects have the same ID at the same time.
   - [Note: this means in particular that different objects can have the same ID at different times, i.e. that IDs can be recycled.]
2. An object ID is an opaque identifier. You *must not* make any assumptions about its structure or about any particular value.
3. Any particular implementation of object IDs is a private internal implementation detail of a specific version of a specific implementation running in a specific environment at a specific moment. There is no guarantee that the results will be the same with a different implementation. There is no guarantee that the results will be the same with a different version of the same implementation. There is no guarantee that the results will be the same with the same version of the same implementation running in a different environment. In fact, there is not even a guarantee that the results will be the same between two runs of the same code on the same version of the same implementation in the same environment.
4. `ObjectSpace::_id2ref` is an abomination. It should not even exist. It most certainly should not be used. It breaks object-orientation, it breaks encapsulation, it breaks safety.

Just as an example: unfortunately, you don't say which version of which implementation you are running in which environment. However, it looks like you are running YARV 2.6.3 in a 64-bit environment.

If you were to run that exact same code on the exact same version of YARV in a 32-bit environment, you would get different results. If you were to run that exact same code on an older version of YARV (pre-2.0) in the exact same environment, you would get different results.

Let's address the first, implicit, assumption which I *think* I see in your question. You seem to think that any ID should resolve to an object. It's easy to see that this cannot be true: there are infinitely many IDs, but for every run of a program, there are only finitely many objects, so there will always be infinitely many IDs which don't resolve to an object.

This already explains most of your results, namely the ones for `4`, `16`, `32`, `64`, `256`, `512`, and `1024`.

So, with that out of the way, here's a high-level explanation of why there seems to some sort of structure to the IDs, and what that structure is. (But let me remind you again, that this explanation only applies to 64 bit systems, not to 32 bit, it only applies to YARV, it only applies to versions of YARV 2.0 or newer, and it is quite possible that it will no longer apply to YARV 3.0.)

In YARV, the developers made the decision that the object ID is the same thing as the memory address of the object header. This makes it easy to ensure the "rules" of object IDs: you can't have multiple objects at the same memory address at the same time, and an object will not change its memory address.

(Actually, it turns out that the second one is already a quite severe restriction: many modern high-performance garbage collectors depend on being able to move objects around in memory. This is not possible if you assume that object ID == memory address. Which means you will not be able to use any of those high-performance algorithms.)

On pretty much all modern machines, memory access is *word-aligned*. While it is possible to address individual bytes, that is generally slower or more awkward. So, we can basically assume that if we allocate memory, it will be aligned on a word-boundary. Which means that all memory addresses will be divisible by 8 on 64-bit systems and 4 on 32-bit systems, or in other words, that all memory addresses will end in 3 (64-bit) or 2 (32-bit) zero bits. Or, in other words: 87.5% (75%) of the address space are unused.

On the other hand, it would be quite a waste to represent `Integer`s as a full-blown Ruby object:

- They are *immutable*, which means we don't have to store any state.
- They can't have instance variables, which means we don't have to store an instance variable table.
- They can't have a singleton class, which means we don't have to store a `__klass__` pointer.
- They can't be `extend`ed.
- And so on …

What this means, is that we can *optimize* the representation of `Integer`s by not storing them as objects at all. All we need is some special case in the engine, so that if someone asks for the `class` of, say, `42`, instead of trying to look at `42`'s `__klass__` pointer, the engine "magically" knows to just return the `Integer` class.

Once we have that in place, we can do a really cool trick, which is actually as old as the very first LISP and Smalltalk VMs, and it is called a *tagged pointer representation*. Normally, the value of a variable is a *pointer* to the object (header), but with a *tagged pointer* representation we can store the *value* of the object *inside the pointer to the object* itself!

All we need to do is to have some sort of *tag* on the pointer that tells the engine that this is actually *not* a pointer but a value disguised as a pointer. In some older machines, especially those specifically designed for running high-level languages, pointers did have a *tag field* specifically for holding, e.g. type information or access control. Modern machines don't have that, but we have those unused bits we can (ab)use as tag bits.

And that is what YARV is doing: When the last bit of a pointer is `1`, then it's not actually a pointer, it's an `Integer`. In particular, an `Integer` is encoded in YARV by shifting it one bit to the left and setting the last bit to `1`. This allows us to encode a 63-bit `Integer` in a 64-bit pointer, and do native integer arithmetic at it with no object overhead and only a little bit of bit shifting overhead.

And if you think about what this encoding means:

- shifting one bit to the left is equivalent to multiplying by two
- setting the last bit to `1` is equivalent to incrementing by 1

Then you can explain the first pattern: a small `Integer` with value `n` is encoded as the "quasi-pointer" `2n + 1`, and since "memory address" and object ID are the same in YARV (even though this is not actually a memory address, because there is no object which could have an address), it will have the object ID `2n + 1`.

`Integer`s that don't fit into 63 bit (31 bit), are allocated as objects like any other object. In different engines, these have different names, e.g. in the Smalltalk-80 VM, they are called `SmallInt`s, in YARV, they are called `Fixnum`s (and the ones that don't fit into a `Fixnum` are called `Bignum`s). They actually used to be different subclasses of a fully-abstract `Integer` class in older versions of YARV, but this was considered a mistake. (It's really an internal optimization and should not be visible to the programmer.) In current versions of YARV, `Fixnum` and `Bignum` are aliases for `Integer` and using them gives a deprecation warning.

This explains your result for `1`. If you had tried out `ObjectSpace._id2ref(3)`, the result would have `1`, then `ObjectSpace._id2ref(5)` would be `2`, and so on.

And we still are using only 62.5% of the address space (on a 64-bit system)!

So, let's think about what else we might want to represent in this way.

YARV has a very similar optimization for `Float`s. Floating point numbers that fit into 62-bits are called *flonum*s and are represented similar, with a tag of `10` at the end. (YARV does not use flonums on 32-bit platforms.)

This explains your result for `ObjectSpace._id2ref(2)`. If you had tried `ObjectSpace._id2ref(6)`, the result would have been `-2.0`.

And a similar trick is also played for `Symbol`s. I won't explain it here in detail, because a) I don't actually fully know how it works, and b) it is slightly more complex, because the value being encoded isn't directly the `Symbol` value, rather it is an index into the `Symbol` table. However, that explains your result for `128`.

Now, lastly, there is a completely different part of the address space that is also unused: the low addresses. On most modern Operating Systems, the low addresses are reserved for mapping the kernel memory directly into the user process in order to speed up the user space ↔︎ kernel space transition. Plus, there is another reason the *very* low addresses are kept free: in C, it is illegal to dereference a `NULL` pointer. Now, one way of implementing this, would be for the runtime to track all pointer dereferences and check whether they are dereferencing the `NULL` pointer. But there is an easier way: just give the `NULL` pointer an *actual* memory address, but one that is never allocated. That way, you don't have to do anything: if the code tries to dereference the pointer, the address doesn't exist, and the MMU will take care of raising an error. So, most C compilers compile the `NULL` pointer to the actual memory address `0`, and in order to make sure that there is never any real data allocated at that address, they keep a whole area around address `0` free.

This means that the low addresses are never used, and we can (ab)use them to represent even more "interesting" objects. Now, YARV uses the very low addresses to represent the following objects:

- `false` at address `0`, which has the additional advantage that `0` is considered *false* in C.
- `nil` at address `8` (`4` in 32-bit).
- `true` at address `20` (`2` in 32-bit).
- `Qundef` (a special internal value inside the engine that denotes an undefined value) at address `52` (`6` in 32-bit).

And that explains your number 8.

This also means that your `4`, `16`, `32`, `64`, `256`, `512`, and `1024` will probably never resolve to an object, because they are in the low address range where the C library will simply never allocate memory.

As a closing remark, I want to repeat one last time that all of this is a *private internal implementation detail* of a specific version of YARV running in a specific environment. You *must not* rely on any of this, ever.

When *flonum*s were introduced in YARV, and on some platforms `nil` no longer had object ID `4`, this *did* break some code, and it *did* cause some confusion (as evidenced e.g. by questions on Stack Overflow), even though the YARV developers are allowed to change object IDs at will, because there are *no* guarantees being made about any particular ID values or the structure of IDs. Please, do not make the same mistake.